# How To Deploy Web Application To cPanel with .war file?

Tags: web-applications, deployment, cpanel, war

I have made my web application and I would like to put it in internet. I have heard that a user can deploy a web application in cPanel by using .war file. I have been searching about this, any kind of tutorial or any information on how to do it. But there's none that actually tells you how to do it, you will find only tutorials on how to deploy on Tomcat or Glassfish. Am I missing some point here? How I can put my web application to internet once its packed as .war file? If I want to deploy my web application to my web hosting account, is it possible? If yes, then how do I do it and do I need to create a database in cPanel or is it (database) included in the .war file if I have created them already?

I have big confusion cloud on my head about this issue. All help is really appreciated.

Comment: Another deployment methods see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994145/can-i-deploy-a-spring-boot-application-on-godaddy/44994422#44994422

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found solution for this. There's Java Web Hosting and Web Hosting. The big difference between those web hosting is that Java Web Hosting support web applications made with virtual servers like Tomcat and GlassFish and others as well.

So anyone who is looking for deployment of web application that is made with Java or JavaEE technologies to internet should be looking Java web hosting instead of web hosting. You can Google to find more information about Java web hosting providers.

As for example [eApps](http://www.eapps.com) is one provider that provides Java web hosting.

Comment: Or, cPanel also handles .war deployment.  https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Deploy+Java+Applications