# Can I deploy a Spring Boot application on godaddy

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, cpanel

Can I deploy a Spring-Boot application on godaddy
using Web hosting and cPanel?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I think it's a fair question but it is more suitable for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. If you're using **Web hosting (shared)** plans according to [Godaddy details](https://www.godaddy.com/hosting).

I Suggest the answer from [Amir Al](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383625/how-to-deploy-web-application-to-cpanel-with-war-file?rq=1).

For more information:

**Web hosting (Shared)** usually limits the Web technology you can use.
However, they're cheap and easy to set up a Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla etc.
So, if you use `spring-boot`, search **Java web hosting**

**Virtual Private Server (VPS) and Dedicated Server** will unlock the web hosting limitation because you have to do it by yourself.
*However, if you're not familiar with Linux (Ex. CentOS / Ubuntu) command line. you can try Window VPS.* If it looks so expensive, move to the cloud. I suggest a free trials or ~5USD package with **Digital Ocean, Google Cloud, Amazon lightsail**, and so on

**Platform as a Service (PaaS)** such as **heroku**. If Linux command line seems to be hard work for you. This choice gives you a shortcut to deploy your target application. *However you have to learn about Git and their tools*.

So, if you want to deploy `spring-boot` use:

1. Java web hosting
2. Cloud PaaS
3. VPS

Answer (score 0):

Nodtem66 - Thanks for sharing the information. It helped me a lot.

In addition to what is mentioned above. I figured out there are 2 ways of hosting a java based application:

1. Purchase a VM (VPS, PaaS) - This is higher in cost if the only need is to have a single webpage application hosted

2. Pay for only Java Hosting - This is much lesser
Few of them I came across are:

https://www.hioxindia.com/linux-dedicated-jvm-hosting.php

https://www.ewebindia.com/java-hosting.html