# How can i deploy spring boot application in godaddy vps in tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, deployment, vps

I want to deploy springboot application on godaddy vps server. and application should load on giving website name. I want the application to be running forever unless i explicitly showdown the tomcat. My springboot application is configured to run on port 8090

I have already installed java and tomcat in vps server. It is ISPconfig server. But i am not sure about working of ISPConfig Server.

1. I could run jar file with emmbedded tomcat. But application shuts down as soon as end the putty session. I tried using screen command but with that also application is not running forever
2. When I host the application usinf jar. It is not accessible through domain name. I have to use ip addess : port number for that. So how can i host the application at 88 port. and override the default webpage of godaddy ?
3. I tried putting war file in webapps of tomcat folder and started tomcat. but with that also i am not able to run the application.

Comment: Maybe you should do a little bit more [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994145/can-i-deploy-a-spring-boot-application-on-godaddy) with regard to this subject.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps you need to follow in order to deploy over VPS on GoDaddy.
Assuming you are using Linux.

1. Create a service which will keep running the jar/war file at start-up and keep it alive.
2. Install NGINX which will help you configure web service with the IP or domain url.
3. In /etc create conf file which will specify all server configurations as written below:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name <IP_OR_URL>;

        location / {
             proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }
}
```

4. Then restart NGINX server and changes will be reflected